# Fetching data from database to drop down list

Tags: php, dropdown

Sorry for asking a duplicate question. I tried few ways given on this website for fetching data. But any of them did not work. I'll put my coding down below.

```
<?php


                mysql_connect('localserver', 'root', '123');
                mysql_select_db('database');
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } else {
                  echo "Connected successfully";

                $sql = "SELECT name FROM company";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                echo "<select name='name'>";
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                }


?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error you've got and the provide $result value for a solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use this code.

Make sure you have the correct credentials.

establish your DB connection :

```
<?php 
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "password";
     $dbname = "db";
     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

     $sql = "SELECT name FROM company";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     $conn->close();?>
```

Then to view the results in your html:

```
<select name="name">
        <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
            }
        ?>
</select>
```

I think this would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Miggy. Your code is working 100%. Legend!

Comment: Thanks @RyanOscar :)